# Correctly Enumerating through a Hashtables values in a ForEach-Object Loop

Tags: powershell

Firstly the Hashtable (Called `$MyHashTable`) looks like this:

```kotlin
Name                           Value
----                           -----
NTER 1                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file1]}
NTER 2                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file2]}
NTER 3                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file3]}
NTER 4                         {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file4]}
LA2 1                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file5]}
LA2 2                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file6]}
LA2 3                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file7]}
LA2 4                          {[Short, Kill > Dump], [Long, Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file8]}
```

I want to use this Hashtable in a `ForEach-Object` loop, where  `$MyHashTable.Name`  will be used as a name for the file in the loop, and `$MyHashTable.values.long` will be used as MetaData for this same file. The output should be:

[image]
In a my file manager:
[image]

Here is a snippet of my code (the part where the files are being generated):

```
    $MyHashTable.keys | ForEach-Object {

        # First Copy the files to their folder

        Copy-item -path 'C:\Temp\Template 2.svg' -Destination "C:\Temp\$_.svg"

        foreach ($Key in $MyHashTable.values.long) {

            # Then Populate their Column Data

            set-metadata  -path "C:\Temp\$_.svg" -Misc1 $key}
            }
```

The files copy fine with the desired names but `foreach ($Key in $MyHashTable.values.long)` loop just gives every file the same MetaData Value ("Procces is terminated, then all errors are dumped to a log file1"
Each of these commands and expressions (`Set-MetaData`, `$MyHashTable.values.long` etc  ) work just fine indvidually on their own. Just putting them together...

I've litterally been at this for hours and tried a number of things: diagnosing the issue, searching stackoverflow for alternatives etc I cannott get around. So close... Please help!

Comment: You really only need one loop, unless your intentions are to set the values of `long` to every file passed to it from your hashtable. Since hashtables aren't enumerable by default, you need to call on `.GetEnumerator()`. Would be helpful if you provide a raw hashtable we can copy and paste to use for our own purposes

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Thanks for pointing the `.GetEnumerator()`. I will start reading up on it. Going forward I will also share my hashtables!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve read your different posts and it seems you simply need to do this

```
$MyHashTable.keys | ForEach-Object {

    # First Copy the files to their folder
    Copy-item -path 'C:\Temp\Template 2.svg' -Destination "C:\Temp\$_.svg"

    # Then Populate their Column Data
    set-metadata  -path "C:\Temp\$_.svg" -Misc1 $MyHashTable[$_].long
}
```

Comment: You know in Hindsight, I can say thats exactly thats what I was trying to express but it just does not do your post any justice. This is brilliant! I really love HashTables so your example is going to come in handy more often. Thanks so much